# Scala - how to implement Try inside a map function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, nullpointerexception

I have one stage of a Spark job failing due to a  `java.lang.NullPointerException` thrown by a function in a `map` transformation.

My idea is to get the corrupted Sale object from inside the `map` with the help of a `Try` type. 
So I intentionally assigned the function result to a `saleOption` variable in order to then do pattern matching.

Unfortunately my current implementation does not work and I need an advice on how to fix it. Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Here is the initial method:

```
  def filterSales(rawSales: RDD[Sale]): RDD[(String, Sale)] = {
    rawSales
      .map(sale => sale.id -> sale) // throws NullPointerException
      .reduceByKey((sale1, sale2) => if (sale1.timestamp > sale2.timestamp) sale1 else sale2)
  }
```

Here is how I implemented my idea:

```
def filterSales(rawSales: RDD[Sale]): RDD[(String, Sale)] = {
      rawSales
      .map(sale => {
        val saleOption: Option[(String, Sale)] = Try(sale.id -> sale).toOption
        saleOption match {
          case Success(successSale) => successSale
          case Failure(e) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Corrupted sale: $rawSale;", e)
        }

      })
       .reduceByKey((sale1, sale2) => if (sale1.timestamp > sale2.timestamp) sale1 else sale2)
      }
```

**UPD:** My intention is to implement the idea for debugging purposes and to improve my Scala knowledge. I'm not going to use `Try` and `Exceptions` for flow control.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the rawSales RDD was created without errors? maybe you can built it so you will have rawSales: RDD[Option[Sale]]... 2. Why are you throwing an exception? you should filter it out.

Comment: @user3725190 Actually I should have mentioned that my intention was to writhe the code for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just ignore `null` `Sales` then remove these out and don't throw an exception. For example with

```
rawSales
 .flatMap(Option(_))
 .keyBy(_.id)
 .reduceByKey(
   (sale1, sale2) => if (sale1.timestamp > sale2.timestamp) sale1 else sale2
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try` should not be used for flow control. `Exception`s should be used only in exceptional cases. The best solution is to fix your `NullPointerException`. If there shouldn't be any nulls, then you have an error in your code that's generating the RDD. If you expect potential null values, such as from malformed input data, then you should really use an `RDD[(String,Option[Sale])]`.